# Making <div> containers with image borders

Tags: html, css

I would like to write up some css/html for container boxes that I can put on my site in various places (ie- to draw out modules like a calendar on the site's sidebar).

I have 5 images: left, right, top, bottom and background for the div.

The top image is 37 px tall, the bottom image is 22 px tall.

I would ideally like to specify a div height/width and then have it draw the div with the images on the top/bottom/right/left sides, autosized to the div's proportions and not overlapping with each other. I would assume that youd want to use absolute positioning for the non-overlapping bit, but I'm completely unsure of how to make the images resize and stick to each side.

Here's the (very bare) code that I have right now:

```
#top {background: url(container_top.png) no-repeat;}
#container {background: url(container_left.png) no-repeat;}
#right {background: url(container_right.png) no-repeat;}
#bottom {background: url(container_bottom.png) no-repeat;}

<div id="top">
   <div id="container">
       Content post
   </div>
   <div id="right"></div>
   <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The only other caveat is that I only want the top/bottom images to scale horizontally (not to resize on the y axis as well), and the left/right images to scale vertically (not to resize on the x axis as well).

For reference, my images are named:
"container_.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few options. First one is to create four corner divs and four side divs, using the corner images at each corner and a repeatable image for the sides. You can also use a kind of "sliding-door" technique. And if you're a brave guy, use css3 border-images (checkout http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

option one:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
       <div class="top-left"></div>
       <div class="top-right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="bottom-left"></div>
        <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.top { background: url('repeatable.png') repeat-x; }
.top-left { background: url('top-left.png') no-repeat; }
.content .left { background: url('repeatable') repeat-y; }
....
```

for sliding door technique, checkout http://www.google.com/?q=google+css+sliding+doors

Comment: For the option one, my biggest hurdle right now is that I don't know how to get the side images to scale. They're not repeatable images, which is why I'm curious about how to get them to scale with the size of the div (or if that's even possible)